# Grafana parse HTTP get JSON result as source

Tags: json, grafana

I know about the answers to JSON data source questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075040/is-it-possible-to-write-a-grafana-datasource-plugin-without-using-a-external-bac).

It requires an implementation where I would need to run a container which I can not do in my current environment.

I have a jira query like `/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20%3D%20MyProject%20AND%20status%20in%20(Closed)&maxResults=0`

where a typical response would be

```
{
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":0,
    "total":368,
    "issues":[]
}
```

I would like to use "total" as the result I want to display.

So my particular issue would be target a server as a source.

1. Execute a set of HTTP POST / GET calls.
2. Use the last JSON result to get one of the members.
3. Display that in grafana.

Is there a part of grafana that can give me this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that your result is not a time series. All Grafana panels/datasources are designed for time series. You may convert it to time series (in container, lambda function, proxy, ...). Or create text panel in `html` mode and code all your business logic (REST call, parsing, ...) in `javascript`. See [example](https://community.grafana.com/t/rss-feeds-news-feeds/10597/2?u=jangaraj). Just keep in mind, that you need to allow javascript explicitly in configuration from Grafana 6+ and resource endpoint must have allowed CORS requests.